# Handle window.scrollTo on svelte on a single page application

Tags: single-page-application, scrollto, svelte, svelte-3

How can i go to a window position after an update on my Repl example? When i scroll down and click on a card and go back to the main window it allways jumps to the top. I have tried to insert window.scrollTo on afterupdate and also beforeupdate, inside the OpenCard.svelte also inside the App.svelte but i cant figure it out. What would be the best solution for this?

[Repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/8bc7ac08f5b24ff3bb4eb55cf7975a53?version=3.20.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is more than one solution for this**, because this is quite a lot of code for such a question.

one solution would be to add this line to your `showHome` function

```
function showHome() {
    visible = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => window.scrollTo(0,100)); // That's the line
  }
```

**HOW IT WORKS:**

The reason this solution works is because you condition the entire app on the `visible` variable, so after setting `visible = true;` the app hasn't updated yet, and therefore calling `window.scrollTo` immediately will just scroll before the refresh.
thus putting it inside a `requestAnimationFrame` will wait for the next redraw of the DOM, making the scroll only after the DOM's update.

**Another solution** would still require `requestAnimationFrame`,
There's no avoiding it using.
It will require to create a reactive statement like this:

```
$: if (visible) requestAnimationFrame(() => window.scrollTo(0,100));
```

That way your app will always know when to change the scroll based on your `visible` variable's value.

I think you should go with the second solution, it's more stable on future changes.

To learn more about `requestAnimationFrame` and how to use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame